# Explain why an absolute value is omitted in the answer for $e^{-s}\left(1 + \frac{ds}{dt}\right) = 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

### Problem statement:

Solve  $e^{-s}\left(1 + \frac{ds}{dt}\right) = 1$

### Attempted solution:

\begin{align*}
e^{-s}\left(1 + \frac{ds}{dt}\right) &= 1 \\
1 + \frac{ds}{dt} &= e^s \\
ds + (1 - e^s)dt &= 0 \\
\frac{1}{1-e^s}ds + dt &= 0
\end{align*}

At this point let's note that $1 - e^{s}$ actually leads to a solution $s = 0$. Having done this, let's denote $1 - e^s = t$, then $e^s = 1 - t\geq 0$ (note the greater-than sign) which allows to take the logarithm: $s = \ln(1 - t)$. With such a substitution we can now compute the first integral:

$$\int\frac{1}{1 - e^s}\, ds = \int\frac{1}{t}\frac{1}{1 - t}\, dt = \int\frac{1}{t} + \frac{1}{1 - t}\, dt = \ln\left|t\right| + \ln\left|1 - t\right| + \text{const}$$

The module in the second logarithm can be omitted due to $1 - t \geq 0$. However, the module in the first logarith should remain. Returning to the ODE:

\begin{align*}
\ln\left|1 - e^s\right| + s + t + \text{const} &= 0 \\
\left|e^{-s} - 1\right| + \text{const}\cdot e^t &= 0 \\
\end{align*}

At this point I would say that the solution is complete, however the answers section of the book says it can be simplified further to:

$$e^{-s} = 1 + \text{const}\cdot e^t$$

Clearly, it implies that the absolute value can be dropped but I do not understand why.

### Question:

Why can the final absolute value be omitted?

Comment: The only missing argument is that the sign of $e^{-s}-1$ is constant. Why? Continuity + the fact that if $s(t)=0$ for some $t$ then $s(t)=0$ for every $t$. Hence $|e^{-s}-1|=Ce^t$ becomes $e^{-s}-1=\pm Ce^t$ where $\pm$ does not change. Using as a new constant this $\pm C$ finishes the proof.

Comment: @Did ah, that was the trick

Comment: @Did You should post that as an answer

Comment: @Did If you do I'll accept

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the condition

$$ s \le 0 $$

Because if so then clearly

$$ e^{-s} -1 \ge 0 $$

Then it follows by the arbitrariness of the constant that

$$ e^{-s} = 1 - Ce^{t} $$

Which is the same as

$$ e^{-s}= 1 + Ce^{t} $$

But without that condition one cannot make that jump

Comment: There is no extra information about $s$, everything is as in the problem statement

Comment: by module do you mean absolute value signs?

Comment: "without that condition one cannot make that jump" Actually one can very much make it, see my comment to the question.